# ADDRESS() inside an OFFSET() function on excel

Tags: excel

I have the following function which returns the maximum column value location:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(B1:B18),B1:B18,0),1)
```

when I add OFFSET to the function to get the corresponding value in another column it does not work!

```
=OFFSET(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(B1:B18),B1:B18,0),1),1,0)
```

Any other way to do this?

I have two colomns:

```
Time (hours)    Cp (ug/L)
0               0
0.1             26.282
0.25            46.532
0.5             57.046
0.75            57.411
1               55.028
```

I want to find the maximum value in Cp colomn and return the time at that maximum value. In this example, maximum value is 57.411 and it was at time 0.75.. the field should return 0.75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the non-volatile solution.

```
=INDEX(A1:A18, MATCH(MAX(B1:B18), B1:B18, 0))
'or,
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B, 0))
```

fwiw, I have not found many situations where the volatile¹ [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) cannot be replaced with the non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

[image: index_offset]

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: I agree, that's better when the range is predefined. How does it behave with an unlimited range though (A:A and the likes...)? Any effect on performance, memory, something else?

Comment: No perceptible performance hit. An [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair truncates calculation at the extents of the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx).

Comment: Good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `ADDRESS()` returns a string and `OFFSET()` needs a reference, but there's a much simpler method:

```
=OFFSET(A1, MATCH(MAX(B1:B18), B1:B18, 0) - 1, 0)
```

Comment: @shnisaka - Confused rows with columns, try now

Comment: perfect! it is working now! just need to do -1 instead of 0 at the last bit of your equation.

Comment: @shnisaka - why -1? Are you accessing *A[n]*? If so, just replace B1 with A1.

Comment: your code returns 57.411. I want it to return 0.75.

Comment: @shnisaka - that's why i wrote to use A1... I edited the answer now

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `ADDRESS()` in `INDIRECT()`.

This will convert it from text to reference format.